# Is their any way to use asp.net core templates in VS code?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I  am new to asp.net core. Is their any way to add controler templates graphically as we use in visual studio.

Comment: You could use the `aspnet-codegenerator` scaffolding tool from the command line. See [this as an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-mac/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1#scaffold-the-moviecontroller).

Comment: Thanks for your response .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use dotnet CLI command lines to generate your desired templates. here is the list of templates with required commands to generate the templates**

```
Templates                                         Short Name         Language          Tags
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Console Application                               console            [C#], F#, VB      Common/Console
Class library                                     classlib           [C#], F#, VB      Common/Library
Unit Test Project                                 mstest             [C#], F#, VB      Test/MSTest
xUnit Test Project                                xunit              [C#], F#, VB      Test/xUnit
Razor Page                                        page               [C#]              Web/ASP.NET
MVC ViewImports                                   viewimports        [C#]              Web/ASP.NET
MVC ViewStart                                     viewstart          [C#]              Web/ASP.NET
ASP.NET Core Empty                                web                [C#], F#          Web/Empty
ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)      mvc                [C#], F#          Web/MVC
ASP.NET Core Web App                              razor              [C#]              Web/MVC/Razor Pages
ASP.NET Core with Angular                         angular            [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with React.js                        react              [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with React.js and Redux              reactredux         [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
Razor Class Library                               razorclasslib      [C#]              Web/Razor/Library/Razor Class Library
ASP.NET Core Web API                              webapi             [C#], F#          Web/WebAPI
global.json file                                  globaljson                           Config
NuGet Config                                      nugetconfig                          Config
Web Config                                        webconfig                            Config
Solution File                                     sln                                  Solution

Examples:
    dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
    dotnet new xunit
    dotnet new --help
```